# Good historical books on projective geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, projective-geometry

Can you suggest some good book for newbies which gives a solid historical background and good understanding in projective geometry ?

(I have zero background in projective geometry, and the only geometry I know is some rudimentary Eucledian Geometry. I was learning projective goemetry from EGMO Chapter 9, but I couldn't properly understand "projective plane", "points at infinity" etc)

Comment: Basically I don't want overkill stuff, I just wan't a good such book so that I can understand the stuff written http://alexanderrem.weebly.com/uploads/7/2/5/6/72566533/projectivegeometry.pdf (and in particular, the historical motivation behind their developement) properly

Comment: In your place I would go to Projective Geometry google images. Certain concepts are basic, and so are  examplified with images. Then go to their sources. Repetitions allow you to log in what is considered essential on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

A good reference is Coxeter's book *Projective Geometry*. The first chapter should provide enough orientation to get you started, should you choose then to go elsewhere. But you might as well stick with the entire book, if you want to learn the subject.

Other good discussions of the history are in Jeremy Gray's *Worlds Out of Nothing* and the last chapter of Cornelius Lanczos's *Space Through the Ages*.